# In App Purchase issue with SKProduct() in Swift

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am trying to implement In-App purchases into an app I am creating however when I try to 'get' the product I have `var products = [SKProducts]()` however this returns an empty array causing the application to crash. 
I have check off all the tax agreements etc. and when I test it out in apples in app purchase example project the IAPs show up.

The full code where the problem occurs is below.

```
class Model {

        var products = [SKProduct]()

        func getProduct(containing keyword: String) -> SKProduct? {
            // print("The array of SKProducts in Model getProduct is \(products)")
            // let test = products.filter { $0.productIdentifier.contains(keyword) }.first
            print("The products are: \(products)")
            print(products.filter { $0.productIdentifier.contains(keyword) }.first)
            return products.filter { $0.productIdentifier.contains(keyword) }.first
        }
    }
```

The print statements return:
"The products are: []" and 
"nil"

If it helps the full project can be found on GitHub [here](https://github.com/tbraun1551/colorguesser)

Answer (score 1):

You function `getProduct` does nothing else than to print an empty array (`products`), and to filter this empty array and retrieve the first element (which does not exist).
I suggest to use a helper like this (I copied it from somewhere, don't remember where):

```
import Foundation
import StoreKit

class IAPHelper: NSObject, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {

  typealias RequestProductsCompletionHandler = (_ success:Bool, _ products:[SKProduct]?) -> ()
  var completionHandler: RequestProductsCompletionHandler?
  var productsRequest: SKProductsRequest?
  var productIdentifiers: Set<String>
  var purchasedProductIdentifiers: Set<String>?

  // MARK: - Init  

  init(identifiers: Set<String>) {

    // Store product identifiers
    productIdentifiers = identifiers;

    // Check for previously purchased products
    purchasedProductIdentifiers = Set()
    for productIdentifier in productIdentifiers {
      let productPurchased = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: productIdentifier)
      if productPurchased {
        purchasedProductIdentifiers?.insert(productIdentifier)
                print("Previously purchased: \(productIdentifier)");
      } else {
                print("Not purchased: \(productIdentifier)");
      }
    }
    super.init() // must be called after subclass init, but before "self" is used
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
  } // init

  func requestProductsWithCompletionHandler(_ completionHandler: @escaping RequestProductsCompletionHandler) {
    self.completionHandler = completionHandler

    productsRequest = SKProductsRequest.init(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers)
    productsRequest!.delegate = self
    productsRequest!.start()
  }

  // MARK: - Products request delegate

  func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    productsRequest = nil

    let skProducts = response.products
        for skProduct in skProducts {
            print("Found product: \(skProduct.productIdentifier), \(skProduct.localizedTitle), \(skProduct.price.floatValue)");
    }

    completionHandler!(true, skProducts)
    completionHandler = nil
  }

  func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        // NOTE: If this happens on the simulator, close the simulator window and re-run the app. This helps normally !!!
        print("Failed to load list of products. Error: \(error)")
    productsRequest = nil

    completionHandler!(false, nil)
    completionHandler = nil
  }

  // MARK: - Purchase

  func productPurchchased(_ productIdentifier:String) -> Bool {
    return purchasedProductIdentifiers!.contains(productIdentifier)
  }

  func buyProduct(_ product:SKProduct) {
        print("Buying \(product.productIdentifier)");

    let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
  }

  func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction in transactions {
      switch transaction.transactionState {
      case SKPaymentTransactionState.purchased:
        self.completeTransaction(transaction)

      case SKPaymentTransactionState.failed:
        self.failedTransaction(transaction)

      case SKPaymentTransactionState.restored:
        self.restoreTransaction(transaction)

      default:
        print("Error: Unknown SKPaymentTransactionState")
      }
    }
  }

    func completeTransaction(_ transaction:SKPaymentTransaction) {
        print("completeTransaction...");

        self.provideContentForProductIdentifier(transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
    }

    func restoreTransaction(_ transaction:SKPaymentTransaction) {
        print("restoreTransaction...");

        self.provideContentForProductIdentifier(transaction.original!.payment.productIdentifier)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
    }

    func failedTransaction(_ transaction:SKPaymentTransaction) {
        print("failedTransaction...");
        if let error = transaction.error as NSError?, error.code == SKError.paymentCancelled.rawValue {
                print("Transaction error:\(error.localizedDescription)");
        }

        SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
    }

    func provideContentForProductIdentifier(_ productIdentifier:String) {

        purchasedProductIdentifiers?.insert(productIdentifier)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey:productIdentifier)
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification), object: productIdentifier, userInfo: nil)
  }

  func restoreCompletedTransactions() {
    SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
  }

}
```

Comment: how do you initialise the ```IAPhelper``` class in ```didFinishLaunchingWithOptions```? Can you show that as well? I'm having trouble with interrupted purchase and purchased items won't show up until user either restarts the app or make the app go background and then back to foreground

Answer (score 0):

To get products you have to make `SKProductsRequest` and wait for the answer in `SKProductsRequestDelegate` methods.

Create and start request:

```
let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: ids)
request.delegate = self // self is delegate of SKProductsRequestDelegate, see below
request.start()
```

Where `ids` has to be `Set<String>` of you product identifiers.

Conform to `SKProductsRequestDelegate`:

```
extension MyClass: SKProductsRequestDelegate {

    internal func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        print(response.products) // here is your [SKProduct] array
        print(response.invalidProductIdentifiers) // if you put wrong ids they would be here
    } 

    internal func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(error) // something wrong
    }
}
```